# Could not initialize class java.lang.UNIXProcess mac

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

I insallled Android Studio My mac pro. But not Gradle Building.

It make error: ***"Could not initialize class java.lang.UNIXProcess"***

Thanks for your help..